# GZIP Compression not working for javascript/css files in asp.net 4.0

Tags: compression, gzip, asp.net-4.0, yslow

I run YSlow on my application and got Grade F(There are 13 plain text components that should be sent compressed) for **Compress components with gzip** section.

```
http://localhost/Application/Default
http://localhost/Application/Styles/basic.css
http://localhost/Application/Styles/menuheader.css
http://localhost/Application/App_Themes/UserHome/Content.css
http://localhost/Application/App_Themes/UserHome/GridView.css
http://localhost/Application/App_Themes/UserHome/inside.css
http://localhost/Application/App_Themes/UserHome/jquery.autocomplete.css
http://localhost/Application/App_Themes/UserHome/jquery.dataTables.css
http://localhost/Application/App_Themes/UserHome/menuheader.css
http://localhost/Application/App_Themes/UserHome/UserHome.css
http://localhost/Application/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js
http://localhost/Application/Scripts/jquery.simplemodal.js
http://localhost/Application/Scripts/jquery.autocomplete.js
```

then i did the solution given below:

**First try:**

[**CLICK HERE**](http://www.dominicpettifer.co.uk/Blog/17/gzip-compress-your-websites-html-css-script-in-code)

Now i run YSlow and got Grade E (There are 4 plain text components that should be sent compressed) for **Compress components with gzip** section.

```
http://localhost/Application/Styles/menuheader.css
http://localhost/Application/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js
http://localhost/Application/Scripts/jquery.simplemodal.js
http://localhost/Application/Scripts/jquery.autocomplete.js
```

**Why 4 files has not compressed?**

**Second try:**

Revert the changes done in **First Try.**
I did other solution given below:

[**CLICK HERE**](http://jeeshenlee.wordpress.com/2010/08/01/how-to-gzip-on-asp-net-and-godaddy/)

Now i run YSlow and nothing improvement.I got same Grade F (There are 13 plain text components that should be sent compressed) for **Compress components with gzip** section.

**Why this solution not worked for me?**

Which solution should i choose to compress java-script/css files in my application

Thanks